# how to fill color throughout the NSTableHeaderView of view based NSoutlineview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

i had created a view based outline view as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcSly.png).  i filled the row by black color, but the background of disclosure button was not appearing with black background. how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set outlineview indentation as 0 in inspector window .problem solved.